# JSF/Primefaces inline cell editing on xhtml doesnt work

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

was able to have inline edit of each cell under memebername and employee id and not able have a edit on amount field(Note those headers are dynamic was succefully able to show data and column values), couldnot able to have edit enable on amount field, can some one let me know what was issue is. Thanks for your time.

```
<p:dataTable editable="true" editMode="cell"
            var="memberInformation" 
                paginator="true" rows="10"  
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} 
                {FirstPageLink} 
                {PreviousPageLink} 
                {PageLinks}
                {NextPageLink} 
                {LastPageLink} 
                {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                value="#{listTemplate.listofMembers}">
    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" update="@this" listener="#{listTemplate.onCellEdit}"/> 
    <p:column headerText="Name">  
        <h:outputText  value="#{memberInformation.memeberName}" />  
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="EmployeeId">  
        <h:outputText style="cursor:pointer;padding:15px;" value="#{memberInformation.empId}" />  
    </p:column>  
    <p:columns value="#{listTemplate.columnNamesList}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex">  
        <f:facet name="header"> 
          <h:outputText style="cursor:pointer;padding:15px;" value="#{column.columnName}" />      
        </f:facet>
         <p:cellEditor>  
           <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{memberInformation.amount}" /></f:facet>  
           <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{memberInformation.amount}"/></f:facet>  
       </p:cellEditor>  
    </p:columns> 
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: i actually need under amount field, but gave test on membername and id to see if am doing right or worng and they work. but not on amount field though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic columns cannot be editable.

it is said in the User Guide v3.5 : DataTable -> Dynamic Columns (page 139) 
"Features like sortBy and filterBy are supported however advanced features like editing is not."

Comment: Does any other third party components offer above functionality?

Comment: @Jay change <p:columns styleClass="ui-editable-column".... Maybe It can help to you.